# How to install or compile & package a newer dev version of network-manager on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian-stretch, networkmanager

How do I install or compile a newer version of network-manager on Raspbian 9.4 Stretch (Lite)? I'm not a Linux person. If I need to compile it, I need to package it up because I need to distribute it to a lot of remote RPi's fast. I don't want any other unstable or testing packages, just this one.

Comment: `newer version` ... newer than what?

Comment: NetworkManager v1.14.5-dev if possible. I'm not sure which version I have, but nmcli reports v1.6.2 (not sure if nmcli == nm)

Comment: Why do you want to use NM rather than the default network manager dhcpcd?

Comment: I have to deploy some software that depends on network-manager to handle hotspot creation. That software is talking to network-manager over dbus, but the current version of NM crashes that software because of a protocol change. I'm trying to get that software to work by upgrading NM to a newer version.